# Spark-Streaming Checkpoints

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to implement spark streaming checkpoints, using GCS as storage for checkpoints. On enabling the checkpointing causes the performance of the job to degrade. Just thinking if checkpoint can be done on sql or some other storage which would be faster then writing to HDFS or GCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 3.x (and previous version) do not provide native support for checkpointing data directly to a SQL database. You have to checkpoint to a file system or a distributed file system like HDFS/GCS/S3.

Having said that you can write(and also then retrieving) your own custom checkpointing mechanism to a different destination.